# Test the convergence of the sequence.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Test the convergence of the sequence $$a_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left (\sqrt[7]{k^2+1}-\sqrt[7]{k^2-1} \right)$$
So far I managed to prove it's monotonically increasing. I can't show that it's bounded above.

Comment: Hint: $x^7-y^7=(x-y)(x^6+x^5y+\cdots +y^6)$. Let $x=\sqrt[7]{x^2+1}$ and $y=\dots$.

Comment: i would use the integral test

Comment: You could also use the mean value theorem on the function $x \mapsto \sqrt[7]{x}$ to estimate the difference in the sum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I denote for $k \ge 2$
$$A = \sqrt[7]{k^2+1} > \sqrt[7]{k^2-1} = B$$
Then
$$A-B = \frac{A^7-B^7}{A^6 + A^5B + \dots + B^6} = \frac{(k^2+1)-(k^2-1)}{A^6 + \dots + B^6} < \frac{2}{7B^6} = \frac{2}{7(k^2-1)^{6/7}}$$

So your sequence is bounded above by

$$\frac{2}{7}\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k^2-1)^{6/7}} < + \infty$$
which is convergent.

Comment: (+1) but you might want to start your sum at $k=2$  and add the $k=1$ term separately :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For $k\ge2$,
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt[7]{k^2+1}-\sqrt[7]{k^2-1}
&=\frac2{\sum\limits_{k=0}^6\left(k^2+1\right)^{\frac k7}\left(k^2-1\right)^{\frac{6-k}7}}\\
&\le\frac2{7\left(k^2-1\right)^{\frac67}}\\
&=\frac27k^{-\frac{12}7}\left(1-\frac1{k^2}\right)^{-\frac67}\\[3pt]
&\le\frac27\left(\frac43\right)^{\frac67}k^{-\frac{12}7}
\end{align}
$$
Compare the series using the $p$-test.